# mysql: search a value in two columns and return the colum name it was fond

Tags: mysql, sql

for example we have the following table
with columns

```
id a b
 1 1 2 
 2 3 4 
 3 5 6 
 4 7 8
```

and we are looking for the value 7 in column a and column b
is there a way to query the table and return the name of column 'a'????

Answer (score 1):

First select all rows where a or b is 7. Then use a case statement to return the name of the column that's 7.

```
select id,
    case when a = 7
    then 'a'
    else 'b'
    end
from mytable
where 7 in (a,b)
```

Another way using `union all`

```
select id , 'a'
from mytable where a = 7
union all
select id , 'b'
from mytable where b = 7
```

If both a and b can be 7 for the same row then the `union all` query will return ids of rows where both values are 7 once for each column whereas the 1st query will return them only once with value `a`.